# Unexpected result when comparing PHP objects

Tags: php, object

When I compared two different objects, it returns firstly `true`, and than after `print_r` (on objects) returned  `false`.

From PHP manual:

> Two object instances are equal if they have the same attributes and values, and are instances of the same class.

But here, in example, I set different values. Why the result is different between PHP 5.4.0 - 5.5.7?

```
abstract class first
{
    protected $someArray = array();
}     

class second extends first
{    
    protected $someArray = array();        
    protected $someValue = null;

    public function __construct($someValue)
    {
        $this->someValue = $someValue;
    }
}

    $objFirst = new second('123');       
    $objSecond = new second('321');       

    var_dump ($objFirst == $objSecond);    
    print_r($objFirst);    
    var_dump ($objFirst == $objSecond);
```

Result is:

```
 bool(true)
 second Object ( [someArray:protected] =>
 Array ( ) [someValue:protected] => 123 )
 bool(false)
```

But what I expected was:

```
  bool(false)
  second Object ( [someArray:protected] =>
  Array ( ) [someValue:protected] => 123 )
  bool(false)
```

Comment: You have got strange PHP :) It prints false both times at me...

Comment: Look the version PHP 5.4.0 - 5.5.7.

Comment: Ok, on 5.3 it works, on 5.4 something is wrong :D

Comment: Prints true first time here: http://ideone.com/vUSOzI OP's exact code.

Comment: @php_nub_qq, look to comment above

Comment: Well, I am confirming this. See http://3v4l.org/B6qrN - since 5.4.0 it gives true/false. Strange

Comment: This has to be some bug in php. I have swapped the declaration order of properties in second class and we are getting false/false everywhere: http://3v4l.org/6VQ14

Comment: Without knowing exactly why, it seems that the object comparison function of the parent class is being used here (at least since 5.4).

Comment: Actually the print_r seems to be affecting the behaviour - http://3v4l.org/Z8l7r

Comment: Can't be reproduced anymore with current master. (aka bug fixed)

Comment: @Nadir-Sampaoli - your facetious comment aside, look at how quickly the bug was fixed after being identified

Comment: To be fair to PHP, this bug seems like a justifiable punishment for re-declaring the same properties in the child that exist in the parent.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This was a bug in PHP. It's fixed now, see the [commit](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commit;h=7e8e21df0c9aa39278e994b05540b69920201b32). In short:

- If you extend a class and redefine the same property the `properties_table` of the object ends up having a NULL value.
- The [comparison code](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_object_handlers.c#1337) incorrectly aborted comparison when two objects had a NULL value in the `properties_table` at the same index - reporting the objects as equal. That doesn't make sense of course, because it discards all differences in the following properties. This is fixed now.
- The reason why `print_r` changes the result, is that by fetching the properties of the object (`get_properties`) the properties hashtable is rebuilt (`rebuild_properties_table`) which uses entirely different (and correct) comparison code.
- For context, `properties_table` and `properties` are two different ways PHP uses to represent properties - the former being way more efficient and used for declared properties and the latter used for dynamic properties. The `print_r` call effectively makes the object properties dynamic.

Answer (score 4):

Well, ok, Identified as bug in php https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66286.

Also here: [Unexpected result when comparing PHP objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913747/unexpected-result-when-comparing-php-objects#comment31397922_20913747)